# Can I apply for schengen visa from a country other than my country of residence.?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens

As I am holding Indian passport and staying in South Korea at present and I want to go to Germany from Korea directly, so am I permitted to apply for the Schengen visa from here?

If so, what is the procedure? Is there any difference?

Also about the documents as I do not have any Korean bank accounts/ insurance as per rules. So what do I do? I have an ARC, will this suffice?

Comment: The answer is 'yes' in principle. As long as you can make a case that it would be unreasonable to apply in India. Usually they like to see a visa longer than 6 months or a similar document that establishes residence/domicile.

Comment: You should contact German embassy and clarify with them. Sometimes countries serve citizens and legal residents of the country they ar located at only.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in Korea on a residence or long term visa, the German Embassy may allow you to apply for a Schengen visa through it, although it may not if you are there as a visitor/tourist. Its [Seoul Consular Services](http://m.seoul.diplo.de/Vertretung/seoul/de/10Visa/en/__English__ub.html) are done in person.

> Embassy of the Federal Republic of Germany
>   8th Fl. Seoul Square Bldg., 416, Hangang-daero, 04637 Seoul
>   Address in Korean for taxi driver: 서울시 중구한강대로 416 서울스퀘어빌딩 (남대문 경찰서 옆, 구 대우빌딩
>   Tel. 0082-2-748-4114
>   Fax. 0082-2-748-4161
>   E-mail. info@seoul.diplo.de
>
> **Opening hours** (passports, visas and other consular affairs)
>   Monday, Tuesday, Thursday: 09.00 am - 11.30 am
>   (collection of passport, visa, etc. until 12:00 am)
>   Wednesday: 02.00 pm - 04.30 pm
>   Friday : 08.30 a.m. - 11.00 am
>   (collection of passport, visa, etc. until 11:30 am)
>
> - All visitors to the Embassy are required to register at the Visitor Desk on the ground floor. You will need a valid photo identification card in exchange for an excess pass to the 8th floor.